# VBA: "For each" loop on a selection: copy certain cells depending position within selection

Tags: loops, excel, select, vba

I will try to explain it as short as possible.

I have a set of files. Within each file there is a sheet with at least two columns. The first column contains the description, the second (and following) columns the values (or in my case a string). The majority of the files just have two columns. Some, however, have more than two columns.

I wrote a first loop that checks whether or not the third column in a file of the list is empty. If it is empty, the file has only two columns and is skipped. Elsewise (if there are more than two columns), a subroutine is run to split the sheet into single files with just two columns.

Important to know is that each column contains information on a project and the first row contains the project name.

My idea was to select the cells within the first row after the 2nd column (e.g. C1 till E1; the number of columns might differ) and run another `for each` loop on that selection.

I have created a empty project description file. Depending on the position of the loop (if its at C1 or D1 or E1), I need the macro to copy the cells below that respective cell (e.g. if the loop is at C1 it should copy C2:C10) and paste it into a fixed position in the empty project description file.

current progress

```
Sub sorter()

Dim mrunner As Workbook
Dim currentwb As Workbook
Dim FileNames As Variant

ThisWorkbook.Activate
Set mrunner = ActiveWorkbook

Range("A:A").Select

For Each FileNames In Selection

    Workbooks.Open Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\old\" & FileNames & ".xlsx"

    Set currentwb = ActiveWorkbook

    If Range("C2") = 0 Then

    currentwb.SaveAs Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\new\" & FileNames & ".xlsx"
    currentwb.Close

    Else

    Call splitter(currentwb,mrunner)

    End If

Next FileNames

End Sub


Sub splitter(currentwb,mrunner)

Dim basewb As Workbook
Dim newwb As Workbook
Dim subname As Variant
Dim master As Range
Dim segment As Range
Dim triggers As Range

Range("C2").Select
Range(ActiveCell, Cells(ActiveCell.Row, Columns.Count)).Select

For Each subname In Selection

    Set master = Range("B1")
    Set segment = Range(currentwb.Cells(subname.Column, 2), currentwb.Cells(subname.Column, 3))
    Set triggers = Range(currentwb.Cells(subname.Column, 4), currentwb.Cells(subname.Column, 43))

    ' save in new worksheet

    Workbooks.Open Filename:=mrunner.Path & "\RisikoTriggerReport_base.xlsx"

    Set newwb = ActiveWorkbook

    Range("B1") = master
    Range("B2") = segment
    Range("B5") = triggers

    newwb.SaveAs Filename:=mrunner.Path & "\new\" & subname & ".xlsx"
    newwb.Close

 Next subname
 currentwb.close

 End Sub
```

If the code is like this the macro runs without any errors. However

```
    Set master = Range("B1")
    Set segment = Range(Cells(subname.Column, 2), Cells(subname.Column, 3))
    Set triggers = Range(Cells(subname.Column, 4), Cells(subname.Column, 43))
```

doesnt work properly. The first row works, but the other two rows do not work. The variables segment and triggers remain empty.

I had tried to refer to a worksheet. So my code looked like this

```
    Set master = currentwb.Range("B1")
    Set segment = currentwb.Range(currentwb.Cells(subname.Column, 2), currentwb.Cells(subname.Column, 3))
    Set triggers = currentwb.Range(currentwb.Cells(subname.Column, 4), currentwb.cCells(subname.Column, 43))
```

But this returned an error. What is the mistake with my thinking? (trying to link the range to a specific workbook?

Answer (score 0):

Your variable subname is actually a range.

When in the `for each` subname becomes the first cell, then the second, ...

Just set part2 based on the column of subname. Notation will be different as `column` returns a number:

```
Dim subname As Range
...
For Each subname In Selection

    Set part1 = currentwb.Range("B1:B3") ' Exists only once in each file 
                                     ' so I can fix the range
    Set part2 = currentwb.Range(currentwb.Cells(subname.Column, 1), currentwb.Cells(subname.Column, 10))
...
Next subname
```

By the way, is currentwb actually a WorkSheet? You need to call `Range` on a sheet, don't you?

Comment: Hi. thanks for your answer. Regarding your first comment: The variable subname is supposed to contain the project names over which the loop is run (combination of numbers and letters) not cells. Do I still define it as Range? Secondly. currentwb is a worksheet that I defined in the first loop. I just woke up and will now try to put the macro together.

Comment: @user3648111 When you loop throught the `Selection` you get a range each time. As you declared `subname` as a variant, it is not a problem. As for the `currentwb` it's just that the name was misleading

Comment: Thank you so much for your input. I have posted my full code below. I think I am close to getting the macro to work. But there are still some issues.

Comment: Well when you have other questions you need to open a new question here or update the existing question if it is minor. In any case don't put that in an answer please

Comment: Okay, I didnt know that. I have deleted the second answer and updated my question post. As I said, the code is accepted but does not bring the expected result. After I run the macro, I do have all the files which all have the correct filename (which means that the variable subname does work properly), however the newly created workbook (the newwb) only has the correct value in Cell B1. The Cells B2 to B43 are empty. (I skipped B4 on purpose)